# How events are drawn on calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, daypilot

I'm working on a project where I have to create a web-based daily event calendar that shows events dynamically. I do understand the general idea behind the backend part of the event calendar

However, I don't understand:

1. How events' boxes/bars are drawn on the table that represents time slots. Are they normal buttons? or something else?

Let's say they are buttons; then:

2. How can we display them on the correct place on the table based on the events' starting and ending times that we get from the backend. i.e. How can we make sure that the events' boxes/bars are drawn from a particular time slot to another time slot?

EDIT : 
I want to customise [daypilot's event calendar](https://code.daypilot.org/17910/html5-event-calendar-open-source)  to create a daily event calendar that displays events dynamically from a backend. I don't want event's name and details to be written on the box representing the event. I want all of the boxes representing events to have the same width but different height depends on the length of the event (see the picture below).

The question is which function/method is responsible for drawing events' boxes on the time slots table?
I hope the question is well described now.

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thank you @Noman for your comment on my question. I  have edited the question and made it more specific.

Comment: Thank you @MGorgon for your comment on my question. I  have edited the question and made it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap calender controls templates with jQuery supported even handlers:

https://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/

https://www.formget.com/bootstrap-calendar/